# Garden Warfare 2, online play with different devices

Tags: plants-vs-zombies-garden-warfare-2

In Plants vs Zombies; Garden Warfare 2, can I play online on my pc with my friend that has an xbox one?

Answer (score 3):

I am afraid **it's not possible** as with most titles, cross-platform play is not possible.

A community manager for EA replied to a similar question to yours on their Answer HQ site:

> No, the game environments are separate, each system (Xbox/PS4/PC) has its own separate player pool.
>
> Interestingly, there has been some rumblings lately in the industry about cross-platform play, but we're not there yet. I suspect it won't be possible to retroactively apply even if it does become the new standard. Besides, it's unlikely that PC and console players would be put together, given the aiming advantage of a keyboard and mouse.
>
> Anyway, forgive my tangent. As mentioned above the answer is a no, sorry.

[Source](https://answers.ea.com/t5/General-Discussion/Playing-PVZGW2-on-Xbox-One-and-PC/m-p/5274486#M9974)